# Как из столбца с датой и временем получить два столбца со значениями минут и секунд?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

Если открыть в фрейме данных файл CSV ([пример файла](https://dropmefiles.com/J45kV)), то получится вот такие слитые дата и время:

```
                   timestamp    size
59  2021-10-06T22:23:39.783Z    30200
60  2021-10-06T22:23:39.799Z    6000
61  2021-10-06T22:23:39.800Z    100
62  2021-10-06T22:23:39.800Z    42800
63  2021-10-06T22:23:39.816Z    100
64  2021-10-06T22:23:44.267Z    400
65  2021-10-06T22:23:51.668Z    1500
66  2021-10-06T22:23:56.677Z    500
67  2021-10-06T22:23:59.881Z    4100
68  2021-10-06T22:24:01.832Z    4000
```

А как сделать еще два столбца, чтобы в одном были только значения минут, а во втором — только значения секунд?

Пример того, что должно получиться:

```
65  2021-10-06T22:23:51.668Z    1500   23  51
66  2021-10-06T22:23:56.677Z    500    23  56
67  2021-10-06T22:23:59.881Z    4100   23  59
68  2021-10-06T22:24:01.832Z    4000   24  1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

для этого достаточно распарсить дату и воспользоваться [атрибутом `.dt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html).

Пример решения в виде однострочника:

```
res = (df
       .assign(t=pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"]))
       .eval("""minutes=t.dt.minute\nseconds=t.dt.second"""))
```

результат:

```
In [351]: res
Out[351]:
                     timestamp  size                                t  minutes  seconds
0     2021-10-06T22:22:20.641Z   100 2021-10-06 22:22:20.641000+00:00       22       20
1     2021-10-06T22:22:20.641Z  2200 2021-10-06 22:22:20.641000+00:00       22       20
2     2021-10-06T22:22:20.641Z   500 2021-10-06 22:22:20.641000+00:00       22       20
3     2021-10-06T22:22:20.641Z   200 2021-10-06 22:22:20.641000+00:00       22       20
4     2021-10-06T22:22:20.641Z   300 2021-10-06 22:22:20.641000+00:00       22       20
...                        ...   ...                              ...      ...      ...
1561  2021-10-06T22:51:35.022Z   600 2021-10-06 22:51:35.022000+00:00       51       35
1562  2021-10-06T22:51:35.087Z   100 2021-10-06 22:51:35.087000+00:00       51       35
1563  2021-10-06T22:51:36.619Z   100 2021-10-06 22:51:36.619000+00:00       51       36
1564  2021-10-06T22:51:36.619Z   100 2021-10-06 22:51:36.619000+00:00       51       36
1565  2021-10-06T22:51:52.532Z   100 2021-10-06 22:51:52.532000+00:00       51       52

[1566 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html => рабочая ссылка из ответа